# Utilizar VIEW en Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

¡Hola, Buenos días!

He encontrado un pequeño problema durante la clase de SQL.
He aprendido como hacer una View, pero no sé cómo utilizarlos.

Por ejemplo: cuando hizo una búsqueda para saber los nombres de los profesores que tienen más de dos reservaciones.

```
CREATE TABLE Profesor (
Profesor_ID integer Departement_ID integer NOT NULL
Nombre varchar(25) NOT NULL
Appelido varchar(25)
Grade varchar(25)
CONSTRAINT CK_Enseignant_Grade CHECK ( Grade IN('Vacataire,'Moniteur','ATER','MCF','PROF')),
Telephone varchar(10)     
DEFAULT NULL,
Fax varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
Email varchar(100) DEFAULT,
CONSTRAINT PK_Enseignement PRIMARY
KEY (Enseignant_ID), CONSTRAINT "FK_Enseignant_Departement_ID
    FOREIGN KEY (Departement_ID)
         REFERENCES Departement (Departement_ID)
            ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT );
```

Hizo:

```
CREATE VIEW Numero_Reservations AS
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Reservaciòn    
        GROUP BY Profesor_ID;

SELECT Nombre, Appelido FROM Profesor e, Numero_Reservaciòn
    WHERE (SELECT COUNT (Profesor_ID)
        FROM Profesor t, Numero_Reservaciòn
        WHERE (t.Profesor_ID = e.Profesor_ID))>=2;
```

Ahí no sé como utilizarlos, porque me da solamente los nombres de todos los profesores...

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: No entiendo bien pero imagino. deseas la cantidad de reservaciones?

Comment: Solamente los nombres de los profesores quienes tienen mas de dos reservaciones.

Comment: Entonces no necesitas crear una vista para tener sólo esa información

Comment: @Lamak , si pero esto fue lo que estaba solicitado en las especificaciones técnicas

Comment: La especificación es que primero debes crear una vista?, Es una tarea?

Comment: @Lamak y entender como utilizarla, lo que esta un poquito 
más técnico. Y no es una tarea sino una investigación personal de lo que podemos hacer con las VIEW

Comment: Mi respuesta no te sirve?

Comment: Es un poco complicado saber que deseas si no se tiene la estructura o campos de la tabla. podrías agregar ¿la

Comment: @ArielOctavioD'Alfeo, si pero ya no puedo decirtelo por lo momento porque ya no No tengo acceso a una computadora. Te lo diré en cuanto sea posible!

Comment: @Elenasys, bien, lo haré.

Comment: @Elenasys, lo hizo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede ser una solución, crear la vista `Numero_Reservations`  a partir de la tabla `Reservacion`, la vista contendría el `Profesor_ID` y `reservations`

```
CREATE VIEW Numero_Reservations AS
    SELECT Profesor_ID, reservations FROM Reservacion    
        GROUP BY Profesor_ID;
```

Y la consulta para obtener los profesores con mas de 2 reservaciones sería:

```
SELECT  * 
        FROM Profesor p, Numero_Reservations r
        WHERE (p.Profesor_ID  = r.Profesor_ID ) and reservations>2
```

Aquí se obtendrían todos los registros de la tabla profesor y de tu vista Numero_Reservations, por supuesto obtendrías nombre y apellido de los profesores con más de dos reservaciones.

Answer (score 2):

La vista seria así:

```
 CREATE VIEW Numero_Reservations AS
      SELECT Nombre, Appelido FROM Profesor e, Numero_Reservaciòn
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT (Profesor_ID)
            FROM Profesor t, Numero_Reservaciòn
            WHERE (t.Profesor_ID = e.Profesor_ID))>=2
    Group by Nombre, Appelido
    having Count(*)>2;
```

y para consultar

```
Select *from  Numero_Reservations
```